# Add legend to gmap python

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to add a legend to a gmap plot?

I'm plotting 6 different scatter graphs onto one map and would like to show the user what each colour represents.

```
gmap.scatter(df1.Latitude, df1.Longitude, '#000000', size=40, marker=True)

gmap.scatter(df2.Latitude, df2.Longitude, 'orange', size=20, marker=True)

gmap.scatter(df3.Latitude, df3.Longitude, 'yellow', size=20, marker=True)

gmap.scatter(df4.Latitude, df4.Longitude, 'white', size=20, marker=True)

gmap.scatter(df5.Latitude, df5.Longitude, 'lightblue', size=20, marker=True)

gmap.scatter(df6.Latitude, df6.Longitude, 'teal', size=20, marker=True)

gmap.draw("map.html")
```

---

So for each of the colours, i'd like it to appear in a legend menu on the map.html file Thanks.

Comment: Does jupyter not have a way to overlay an image? Can't you just use a png?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used that approach before. Any resource?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a jupyter-notebook guy. But I do develop google maps-based webpages for a living, and that's typically how I do legends unless I need something real dynamic. I retagged with the jupyter-notebook tag for you to hopefully get some people who know it to see your question.

Comment: Great thanks! Still learning myself.

Comment: In that case here's a SO tip for you: people who are regular users tend to subscribe to certain tags (I found your question via the google-maps tag). So if your question is language/framework specific, then make sure you include that tag to draw appropriate people to your question. Mousing over a tag will give you a tooltip with a description.

Comment: Is there a solution to this?